# Parsing with beautifulsoup and getting an mp3 link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a webpage to get the FIRST mp3 link ONLY. The html I will be parsing will look like this (in the webpage):

```
<a href="#" playlist="http://dn-naverdic.ktics.co.kr/naverdic/f759cdac78d6e201e5dfd928acc70e2a/4ffec2f7/naverdic/endic/sound/clear/us/007/007582.mp3" class="play3 N=a:wrd.listencom,r:3,i:85c05904f36749e6aa9f6fd3f461f63c">
```

I've tried the find_all function with 'a' as the parameter and tried getting it to find 'playlist' but I could not get it to work.

The code is part of another modified program I found online (lots of lines of code), but the part i'm trying to do for beautiful soup failed on all attempts so I don't really have a sample to post since none of them worked and I kept getting errors.

Comment: -1 Show your code.http://sscce.org/

Comment: There's no code I've gotten to work even remotely successfully. soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    print soup.find("a", "playlist") for example fails

Comment: Nevertheless, show us what you have, and the errors that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do it (too many, maybe.)  This might help you get started:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> url = 'http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?isOnlyViewEE=N&query=Rule'
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
>>> 
>>> playlists = soup.find_all("a", {"playlist": True})
>>> playlists
[<a class="play3 N=a:wrd.listencom,r:3,i:85c05904f36749e6aa9f6fd3f461f63c" href="#" playlist="http://dn-naverdic.ktics.co.kr/naverdic/e883ec39de5d45840c2744705c2918c7/4ffee8ca/naverdic/endic/sound/clear/us/007/007582.mp3">
<img alt="play" class="play" height="18" src="http://dicimg.naver.com/endic/img/play.gif" width="19"/>
</a>, <a class="play3 N=a:wrd.listenuk,r:3,i:85c05904f36749e6aa9f6fd3f461f63c" href="#" playlist="http://dn-naverdic.ktics.co.kr/naverdic/7001326345aadc53fa3911f9083065d7/4ffee8ca/naverdic/endic/sound/uk/0990000/0992050.mp3">
<img alt="play" class="play" height="18" src="http://dicimg.naver.com/endic/img/play.gif" width="19"/>
</a>]
>>> 
>>> playlists[0].get("playlist")
'http://dn-naverdic.ktics.co.kr/naverdic/e883ec39de5d45840c2744705c2918c7/4ffee8ca/naverdic/endic/sound/clear/us/007/007582.mp3'
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Also very helpful in helping me learn beautiful soup. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't have BeautifulSoup on the current machine I'm on, but here is some sample code that uses [lxml](http://lxml.de/).  Perhaps you could show us what code you are using?

```
from lxml.html import etree
from lxml.html import HTMLParser
from cStringIO import StringIO
soup = """<body><a href="#" playlist="http://dn-naverdic.ktics.co.kr/naverdic/f759cdac78d6e201e5dfd928acc70e2a/4ffec2f7/naverdic/endic/sound/clear/us/007/007582.mp3" class="play3 N=a:wrd.listencom,r:3,i:85c05904f36749e6aa9f6fd3f461f63c"></body>"""
root = etree.parse(StringIO(soup),HTMLParser())
root.xpath('//a')
# Will return: [<Element a at 0x30840a0>]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let me be a little more specific, the sample I posted would be code that would come up from the webpage I'm parsing. It would view a webpage like: http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?isOnlyViewEE=N&query=Rule and look for the first mp3 link.